# PageMethods and page controls reference

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, pagemethods

I'm using pagemethods to call a method from javascript, is there a way to access the page's controls from the method in codebehind (marked as static)? The problem is that the pagemethod nedds to load a business entity and load it to the page, and the structure is complex.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Even in a static/shared method you can access your page.

C#:

```
(WebForm1)HttpContext.Current.Handler
```

VB.Net:

```
DirectCast(HttpContext.Current.Handler, WebForm1)
```

Where WebForm1 is your page-type. Then you can access all your controls.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but when I access the Controls property of the page there are none.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot that in a WebMethod no Viewstate is loaded, its not part of the page-lifecycle for performance reasons. So i have no suggestions but to pass values from javascript to this method.

Comment: Is it an option to store relevant controls or objects in the session? You can access session from static context with:
HttpContext.Current.Session